# Are there alternatives to LibreOffice?

Tags: software-recommendation, libreoffice

Is there any alternative to LibreOffice? It seems to unfamiliar to MS office users.

I found while running certain presentations in `.ppt` or `.pptx` it is not fully compatible.

Comment: Which is OS and office version you are using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This really depends on what you actually need from your office apps.

Theres a couple good Writing/Word Processing apps in the Ubuntu Software Center. AbiWord, LyX Document Processor, and Zoho Webservice Word Processor (Ordered from best and pretties, to leasts in my opinion) But I personly use one called "FocusWriter". I really like it cause its very very simple, you can set a background image to be behind your typing, and when started it automatically starts in fullscreen.  Its not available in the Software Center, but can easily be installed by following the tutorial a the bottom of this article about FocusWriter.  [FocusWriter on OMG Ubuntu!!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/09/focuswriter-1-3-0-released/)

There only 2 stand alone spreadsheet apps I find in the Software Center are Gnumeric and Zoho Webservice Spreadsheet. I haven't touched a spreadsheet since I was in middle school, which was a good LONG time before I came to using Linux. So maybe there are other spreadsheet apps out there that I don't know about.

But as far as a stand alone presentation app goes, I don't know of any really sinces again I don't ever make presentations. I know Scribus pops up when searching the Software center for presentation apps, and I know the "Full Circle Magazine" alot to layout their very professional looking publication. I don't know if it can be used to output documents in a presetation format though. Zoho Webservice Presentation is there too so if all else give it a shot. Anyone with more info on this part please chime in.

Now if you want a all included Office Suite. Open Office is still available through the software but not popular cause of all the drama over Oracle being greedy. A good alternative might be KOffice though.

Sorry if I was too long. But hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just wanted to check if any alternatives available.

Answer (score 6):

You can install MS Office 2007 in wine (how to see here:  http://www.webupd8.org/2011/01/how-to-install-microsoft-office-2007-in.html)

Comment: more very important details: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=4992

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely try to use Calligra office apps: Calligra Words, Calligra Stage, Calligra Sheets, Calligra Flow, and finally Krita which is a serious competition to Gimp and Photoshop.

Answer (score 3):

### [Kingsoft Office Suite](http://www.kingsoftstore.com/)

Kingsoft Office is an ambitious clone of Microsoft Office. Right now, it is in beta, but it works fine for me.

#### What I like

- fancy and fast
- easy to use
- some of people say that it has better compatibility with `...x` files (`docx` etc).
- beautiful design

#### What I don't like

- **It's not open source!** (from what I know, that's why I don't use it!)
- the design is very close to Microsoft Office (the people that come from Windows will like it)

### Screenshot

> [image]

### Download

Download it from download page: http://wps-community.org/download.html

Answer (score 2):

Lotus Symphony

http://www-03.ibm.com/software/lotus/symphony/home.nsf/home

Comment: Given that Symphony is based on the OpenOffice code base, I doubt it's `.ppt`/`.pptx` support is any better than LibreOffice.

Answer (score 1):

Office 2007 in Wine can still scramble graphs in pptx. Microsofts Livedrive service provides an online Office that works well as does Google Docs, since both are in browser there are no compatibility problems.

Answer (score 1):

I found the best solution on a machine with at least 2GB RAM to install VirtualBox, install Windows on that virtual machine and then install MS Office in its native OS.

Advantages:

- no compatibility issues whatsoever
- Office in VirtualBox with Windows 7 is actually more reactive and faster than LibreOffice
- VirtualBox allows a good integration into Linux desktop
- you can share folders with Windows, such that you do not have to copy your files to edit them
- good if you need some less popular Windows programs (like EndNote)

Disadvantages:

- you need a copy of Windows
- takes up memory

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [WPS Office](https://www.wps.com/linux). This has the same feel and fully compatible with Microsoft Office (.DOC and .DOCX)